# Activate click only when not clicking on child element as well in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using javascript with JQuery and am running into the following problem:

I assigned a `tr` in a table to go somewhere using the onclick attribute (since you can't use a `a` tag with a `tr`). Since the code was so trivial, I just did inline javascript without JQuery. The issue is that I have another link inside one of the table cells, but when I click that link, the `tr` link gets activated first and I'm sent to the wrong page.

This is what my `tr` link looks like: `onclick="javascript:document.location.href = '/1/display"`

This is one of the JQuery `click`s on a cell. There are regular `a` tag links as well:

```
thi.click(function(e){ // Thi is a a tag.
    open_entry_id = thi.attr('data-id');
});
```

Is there anyway to fix it so that the `tr` link is only used when none of its children are clicked? (By children, I mean children that are clickable. I still want it to link when I click regular text in the `tr`)

Comment: Not related to your question, but there's no need for `javascript:` prefix in `onXXX` attributes; that's only need if you're putting Javascript in `href`.

Comment: Is the link just an ordinary `<a href="URL">` type of link, or does it have Javascript in it, too?

Comment: @Barmar Actually both. I should have specified.

Comment: Don't specify, SHOW the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar I just did. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, use it's [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method on your links. That way the click event on the links won't bubble up (propagate) to the click event on your table rows.

In general:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: I actually have stuff already going on for the a tag using the `click`. I tried adding `e.stopPropogation` to the top of the function (now in my original question.), but it did not work.

Comment: It's `e.stopPropagation`, not `e.stopPropogation`. Did you include the  `e` parameter in the function argument list as well?

Comment: *palm to forehead* Embarrassing typo... It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should prevent [event-bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing). In jQuery this is done with [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). You should put that in the function called by the child.